# Loop through gridview getting error

Tags: sql, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview that I am trying to loop through to get the values to update and store in my database. Gridview code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                Width="1020px" EnableTheming="True" PageSize="25" CellPadding="4" 
                ForeColor="#333333" >
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Column1" HeaderText="Col1" ReadOnly="True" >
                    <ItemStyle Width="35px" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Column2" HeaderText="Col2" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Column3" HeaderText="Col3" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Column4" HeaderText="Col4" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Column5" HeaderText="Col5" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Col6">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Column6") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="$"></asp:Label>&nbsp;
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Column6", "{0:f}") %>' CssClass="boxright"></asp:TextBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Column7" ReadOnly="True" >
                    <ItemStyle Width="35px" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    </Columns>
                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#003399" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#003399" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <PagerSettings Mode="NextPreviousFirstLast" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#003399" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
            </asp:GridView>
```

I am using a button click event to trigger the stored sql procedure to update my table as follows...

```
Protected Sub btnB_Save_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnB_Save.Click
Dim gvRow As GridViewRow
    Dim str As String = ""
    For Each gvRow As GridViewRow In gv_Budgets.Rows
        str = ((str + gvRow.Cells(0).Text) + (gvRow.Cells(1).Text) + (gvRow.Cells(2).Text) + (gvRow.Cells(3).Text) + (gvRow.Cells(4).Text) + (gvRow.Cells(6).Text))
    Dim dtRow As TextBox = CType(gvRow.FindControl("TextBox1"), TextBox)
    Response.Write(dtRow.Text)

    dt = dal.ExecuteStoredProc(DAL.dbType.SqlServer, "UpdateData", "@col1", str + gvRow.Cells(0).Text, "@col2", str + gvRow.Cells(1).Text, "@col3", str + gvRow.Cells(2).Text, "@col4", str + gvRow.Cells(3).Text, "@col5", str + gvRow.Cells(4).Text, "@col6", dtRow.Text, "@col7", str + gvRow.Cells(6).Text, "@txt1", Textbox2.Text, "@txt2", Textbox3.Text)

    Next
End Sub
```

However, I keep getting those blue syntax error lines under my "dt(datatable)" expression... Any ideas on how or why this is doing this?

Comment: What is the exact error it's reporting? If you look in the Errors List window it should give you an exact error on what is wrong.

Comment: Value of type'String' cannot be converted to 'System.Data.DataTable'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the "Variable gvRow hides..." error is happening because you've declared gvRow outside the loop and then redeclared it in the definition of the loop.

```
Dim gvRow As GridViewRow    ' First declaration
Dim str As String = ""
For Each gvRow As GridViewRow In gv_Budgets.Rows    ' Skip the "As GridViewRow here
```

The other error is coming from your expression:

```
dt = dal.ExecuteStoredProc( ...
```

I'm assuming (because you don't have it listed) that dt is some global variable of type DataTable somewhere. In this case it looks like your sProc is returning a string and attempting to insert it into a datatable object. Make sure your sProc returns a valid datatable. In the meantime you may try to insert the result into a string just to get things working until you can work that out.